# xpath expression not returning child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have setup a simple xpath expression which I expected to work right away, I have now tried many variations but am still unable to retrieve the corect information:

```
<xsl:when test="$pageType='siteExtraLinks'">/home/section[name=&apos;Extra&apos;]/instance/*[starts-with(name(),'extraLinks') and boolean(.)]</xsl:when>    
<xsl:when test="$pageType='siteExtraLinksText'">/home/section[name=&apos;Extra&apos;]/instance/*[starts-with(name(),'extraLinks') and boolean(.)]/text</xsl:when>    
<xsl:when test="$pageType='siteExtraLinksHref'">/home/section[name=&apos;Extra&apos;]/instance/*[starts-with(name(),'extraLinks') and boolean(.)]/href</xsl:when>    
<xsl:when test="$pageType='siteExtraLinksExtraText'">/home/section[name=&apos;Extra&apos;]/instance/*[starts-with(name(),'extraLinks') and boolean(.)]/extraText</xsl:when>
```

The XML outputs correctly

```
<extraLinks0>
  <text>text 0</text>
  <href>link 0</href>
  <extraText>extra text 0</extraText>
</extraLinks0>
<extraLinks1>
  <text>text 1</text>
  <href>link 1</href>
  <extraText>extra text 1</extraText>
</extraLinks1>
```

Buts reads incorrectly on the docent

```
text 0 link 0 extra text 0<br />
text 0 link 0 extra text 0
```

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information.  Where is the source XML that those XPaths are referring to? What are you trying to do? _Where_ is it displaying incorrectly?

Comment: all I am trying to usnderstand at this point is why <xsl:value-of select="..."/> is not writing the decendant as listed above.

Comment: Your question doesn't include any uses of `<xsl:value-of>`. How can we tell you how to fix what you're doing if you won't show us what you're doing? And where is the source XML? I see no connection between your first XSLT snippet and the XML in the second snippet. Please explain their connection clearly, preferably with the source XML and a more complete sample of your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by making relative references in the xpath.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: solution `<xsl:when test="$pageType='text'">text</xsl:when>`

Comment: Update your answer with proper explanation if any.